# UITableViewCell Auto Resizing Multiple UILabels

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

We are currently resizing the height of a UILabel in a UITableViewCell.  Now the client wants to have both labels contained within the UITableViewCell to be resized based on the content.  Researching this we see solutions everywhere for resizing a single label but nothing about multiple labels. Can somebody point us to a good resource for this issue?

Comment: do you use autolayout? what is target ios version?

Answer (score 0):

your research for resizing label is correct , you need write the logic for resizing on one label only. if you see in

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

its return type  uitableviewcell. it always return the same configuration for the cell(unless you are creating static cell for each row).

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

this method dequeue the cell & reuse it .  so you need to right the logic for resizing the label where you are creating your cell. or its better to right the resize logic in custom cell class. i am adding the code , which help me in this problem.

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(270, FLT_MAX);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"  size:16.0f] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

NSLog(@"Expected Size of label based on string--%@",NSStringFromCGSize(expectedLabelSize) );
//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = myLabel.frame;//get initial frame of your label
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
myLabel.frame = newFrame;
NSLog(@"new frame of label--%@",NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));
[myLabel setText:attString];
```